# Magento 2.1 Media path in .phtml file

Tags: magento2, media

How to get media path in Magento 2.1. I tried lots of option but it is not working?

I want to display the image in front-end inside .phtml file.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and what were the associated results?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can get media path by **$object** method

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
echo $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

**factories method**

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block;
    use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

    class Banners extends Template
    {

        protected $objectManager;
        public function __construct( 
            ....... 
            ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
                       ...) {

                    ...........
                    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

                    ...............
        }
        public function getMediaUrl(){

            $media_dir = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                ->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

            return $media_dir;
        }
    }
    ........
?>
```

in **phtml** file

```
<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl(); ?>
```

Comment: Please note, for recent versions (Magento 2.1+), using **ObjectManager** is discouraged, please see more relevant answers below for getting it in more recommended ways.

Answer (score 19):

Usage of Object Manager is discouraged as per Magento's coding standards. In a template file, we can get the media URL using the following code:

```
$this->helper('\Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images')->getBaseUrl()
```

As per the Magento's recommendation, the document root of your website should be outside `pub` directory during development and it should be inside `pub` directory when moved to production.

Hence we cannot hard code the `pub` directory while getting media URL in the template files. The above code will give you the correct media URL irrespective of your document root location.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer I have come across 

Answer (score 8):

**Get media path by objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
echo $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

**Get media path by Dependency Injection**

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct( 
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    ...
}

public function getMediaUrl()
{
    $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager
                     ->getStore()
                     ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    return $mediaUrl;
}
```

Now call function `getMediaUrl()` in **phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Don't use objectManager**

#### Magento 2. Get media URL in template file

You can get media url in your template file using below way but without using objectmanager you must have to define Block file with __construct() method with define storeManagerInterface in construct method.

In your phtml Block file create __construct function.

Add to `__construct` in your class

```php
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Add new method in your class

```php
  
  public function getMediaUrl($path)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path;
    }
```

Call in `phtml`

```
  <img src="<?php echo $block->getMediaUrl('wysiwyg/img.jpg') ?>" />
```

This is the +- proper way to get media url in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

> $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

Please check this code. It will give you media path.

Comment: This does not work in a .phtml file because the _storeManager property is protected